# .NET Core 3.1 Worker as windows service not starting on Windows server but working on local system

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a worker service in .NET Core 3.1. I installed it on my local system and working fine. But when I installed it on Windows server, service not started.
Here is my code

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<ClassWaitlistWorker>();
                services.AddHostedService<ServiceWaitlistWorker>();
                services.AddHostedService<WaitlistHistoryWorker>();
            });
}
```

Comment: I can add more code for Worker class if needed to understand

Comment: I don't think it would be appropriate to host a worker service in IIS. IIS is a web server and worker services are supposed be daemonized.

Comment: https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-web-hosting/four-reasons-why-your-asp-net-core-application-is-not-working-in-iis

Comment: @ruzgarustu: Hosting bundle has nothing to do with this. This is a service worker not ASP.Net

Comment: My mistake, Actually I installed it on windows server not on IIS.